# How to dynamically update center layoutunit content from menuitem in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.5 with JSF 2.0 on Tomcat 7.0. I am trying to accomplish seemingly a simple task of dynamically loading a center layoutunit section of a fullPage layout when selecting a menuitem. I have spent last couple of days researching this problem and none of the answers that I am running into seem to work. When menuitem is selected then the center layoutunit section goes blank.

Here is my layoutTemplate.xhtml that defines two layoutunits top and center with two template sections menu and center inside each.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>ESF-12 Control Panel</title>
        </f:facet>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-layout-north {
                z-index: 20 !important;
                overflow: visible !important;;
            }

            .ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
                overflow: visible !important;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" size="50">
                    <ui:insert name="menu">Top Section</ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit> 
            <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
                    <ui:insert name="center">Center Section</ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Here is my home.xhtml that uses the layout and defines values for menu and center sections.

```
<ui:composition template="/layoutTemplate.xhtml"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p= "http://primefaces.org/ui">

     <ui:define name="menu">
         <ui:include src="/menu.xhtml" />
     </ui:define>
     <ui:define name="center">
         <ui:include src="#{viewControllerBean.view}" />
     </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is a simple ViewControllerBean.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ViewControllerBean {

private String view = "/centerLayoutUnit1.xhtml";

/**
 * @return the view
 */
public String getView() {
    return view;
}

/**
 * @param view the view to set
 */
public void setView(String view) {
    this.view = view;
}
}
```

Here is my menu.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="Test" icon="ui-icon-power">
                    <p:menuitem value="Change Center Layout" icon="ui-icon-pencil" update=":center" actionListener='#{viewControllerBean.setView("/centerLayoutUnit2.xhtml")}'/>
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally two xhtml files that I want to use to populate the center layoutunit template content.

Here is centerLayoutUnit1.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        Center Layout Unit 1
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is centerLayoutUnit2.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        Center Layout Unit 2
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

All help is very much appreciated!!!